# Expressing pseudo code as a function of n

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I want to express what this pseudo code returns as a function.

```
function mystery(n)
    r := 0
    for i:= 1 to n-1 do
        for j:= i+1 to n do
            for k:= 1 to j do
                r:= r+1
    return r
```

I believe it may be something along the lines of f(n) = n*(n-1)^2
but I don't think that's quite right. Can some one explain if this is correct and if false then how should I go about arriving to a proper answer.

Comment: Related question - [Time complexity of a triple-nested loop](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/3306).

Comment: Expand and use highest term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute the function one loop at a time:

```
for k:= 1 to j do
    r:= r+1
```

Call this function `K(j)`. It should be pretty obvious that `K(j) = j`.

Now let's go out one loop:

```
for j:= i+1 to n do
    r:=r+K(j)
```

Call this function `J(i)`. Doing a bit more work, you should see that `J(i) = (i+1) + (i+2) + ... + n`. There's a mathematical formula for this kind of sum (I'll leave it up to you to figure this one out).

Now finally, the last loop:

```
for i:= 1 to n-1 do
    r:=r+J(i)
```

And then you do a little more work here to get your final answer.